# Selecting attributes by coordinates from DataFrame in Python

Tags: python, coordinates, tiles, pandas, data-frame

I wonder how to return the right information needed from this `df`. Currently I get an empty return. I think the problem is my selection because the coordinates are correct and all variables are as well. If I take away just one `&` from the selection it seems to work,  The code is running like this, you can try your best. I really think it's just a little thing missing here.

Who can help?

```
import os, requests
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.11f' % x)

#example bounds
xmax, ymax, xmin, ymin = 3845447.52241509, 8560465.238354621, -2057434.3252381992, 4031530.0276551154

direc = os.getcwd().replace('\\', '/')
#wd
url = 'https://modis-land.gsfc.nasa.gov/pdf/sn_bound_10deg.txt'
tiles_txt = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)

open(direc+'/tiles_bounds.txt', 'wb').write(tiles_txt.content)
text = open(direc+'/tiles_bounds.txt', 'r').read()
text = text.splitlines()
del text[0:7] 
del text[-2:]

v,h,hv = [],[],[]
for iv in range(len(text)):
    v.append('v' + text[iv][1:3].replace(' ', '0'))
for ih in range(len(text)):
    h.append('h' + text[ih][5:7].replace(' ', '0'))
for VH in range(len(text)):
    hv.append( h[VH] + v[VH] )

df_bounds = pd.DataFrame(columns=['tile','horizontal', 'vertical','xmin_m','xmax_m', 'ymin_m', 'ymax_m'])
df_bounds['tile'] = hv

hor, ver, xmin_m, xmax_m, ymin_m, ymax_m=[], [], [], [],[], []
for h in range(len(df_bounds['tile'])):
    hor.append(df_bounds['tile'][h][1:3])
    ver.append(df_bounds['tile'][h][4:6])
df_bounds['horizontal'] = hor
df_bounds['vertical'] = ver
df_bounds['horizontal'] = df_bounds['horizontal'].astype(int)
df_bounds['vertical'] = df_bounds['vertical'].astype(int)

tile_width = 1111950.5196666666
tile_height = 1111950.5196666666

for i in range(len(df_bounds['tile'])):
    xmin_m.append(-20015109.354 + df_bounds['horizontal'][i] * tile_width)
    ymin_m.append(-10007554.677 + (17 - df_bounds['vertical'][i]) * tile_height)
df_bounds['xmin_m'] = xmin_m
df_bounds['ymin_m'] = ymin_m

for i in range(len(df_bounds['tile'])):
    xmax_m.append(df_bounds['xmin_m'][i] + tile_width)
    ymax_m.append(df_bounds['ymin_m'][i] + tile_height)

df_bounds['xmax_m'] = xmax_m
df_bounds['ymax_m'] = ymax_m
#####here its's broken HERE
################################################################################################
tile_names = df_bounds['tile'][(df_bounds['xmin_m'] >= xmin) & (df_bounds['xmax_m'] <= xmax) & (df_bounds['ymax_m'] <= ymax) & df_bounds['ymin_m'] >= ymin]
####################################################################################################
tile_names = [i + ',' for i  in tile_names]
tile_names = list(tile_names)
tile_names = ''.join(tile_names)
tile_names = tile_names[:-1]
os.remove(direc + '/tiles_bounds.txt')

print(df_bounds, '\n', '\n')
print(tile_names)
```

Comment: have you consider using geopandas ?

Comment: Yes, geopandas is not very compatible with QGIS plugins. I will not use it.

Comment: and so on the line you higlight, the commented conditions are making the code bug right ?

Comment: Yes the commented line returns the bug.

Comment: Okay, there was one condition commented, so it shouldn't return anything now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I tested your code. `df_bounds`is a file composed of [648 rows x 7 columns]. So it seems to work. so the problem comes from the way you create the tile_names variable.

I tested individually each one of you're condition and they should work, but written as you written it it can't because you forgot a paranthese at the last condition:

```py
tile_names = df_bounds['tile'][(df_bounds['xmin_m'] >= xmin) & (df_bounds['xmax_m'] <= xmax) & (df_bounds['ymax_m'] <= ymax) & (df_bounds['ymin_m'] >= ymin)]
```

To debug it I needed to sanythise your code so there is no reason to keep it for myself.

- You should stop using `os.path` and use `pathlib.path` object instead as suggested in this article (https://treyhunner.com/2018/12/why-you-should-be-using-pathlib/).
- You should look into the `map` method when you want to create a new DataFrame column from an existing one it's way more efficient (and easier to read) and try to avoid multiple for loop it makes simple things look complicated.
- Always open files with a `with`statement it will ensure that you never forget to close them
- you can directly use the `join` function on `pd.Series`

```py
import requests 
from pathlib import Path

##########################
##      parameters      ##
##########################
tile_width = 1111950.5196666666
tile_height = 1111950.5196666666

# example bounds 
xmax, ymax, xmin, ymin = 3845447.52241509, 8560465.238354621, -2057434.3252381992, 4031530.0276551154

# todo : to name in parameters 
toto = -20015109.354
tutu = -10007554.677
##########################


# use the pathlib lib it's easyer to manipulate files and folder and I helps you get rid of compatibility problems
direc = Path().cwd()

#wd
url = 'https://modis-land.gsfc.nasa.gov/pdf/sn_bound_10deg.txt'
tiles_txt = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)

tile_bounds = direc.joinpath('tiles_bounds.txt') 
tile_bounds.write_bytes(tiles_txt.content)

# always open files with a with statement to avoid unclosed files
with tile_bounds.open() as f:
    text = f.read()
    text = text.splitlines()

    del text[0:7] 
    del text[-2:]
    
# the file is now useless unlink it 
tile_bounds.unlink()
    
df_bounds = pd.DataFrame(columns=['tile','horizontal', 'vertical','xmin_m','xmax_m', 'ymin_m', 'ymax_m'])
#df_bounds.tile = hv

hor, ver, xmin_m, xmax_m, ymin_m, ymax_m=[], [], [], [],[], []

# use the map function to add extra column to a dataframe, it's easier and faster 
df_bounds.tile = [f"h{text[i][5:7].replace(' ', '0')}v{text[i][1:3].replace(' ', '0')}" for i in range(len(text))]
df_bounds.horizontal = df_bounds.tile.map(lambda row: row[1:3]).astype(int)
df_bounds.vertical = df_bounds.tile.map(lambda row: row[4:6]).astype(int)
df_bounds.xmin_m = df_bounds.horizontal.map(lambda r: toto + r*tile_width)
df_bounds.ymin_m = df_bounds.vertical.map(lambda r: tutu + (17 - r)*tile_height)
df_bounds.xmax_m = df_bounds.xmin_m.map(lambda r: r + tile_width)
df_bounds.ymax_m = df_bounds.ymin_m.map(lambda r: r + tile_height)

#filter the names of the tiiles inside the box
tile_names = df_bounds[(df_bounds['xmin_m'] >= xmin) & (df_bounds['xmax_m'] <= xmax) & (df_bounds['ymax_m'] <= ymax) & (df_bounds['ymin_m'] >= ymin)]

# improvement for the print 
tile_names = ','.join(tile_names.tile)

print(tile_names)
```

which returns :

```
h17v02,h18v02,h19v02,h20v02,h17v03,h18v03,h19v03,h20v03,h17v04,h18v04,h19v04,h20v04
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You really helped me learn something useful about good style.

Comment: if it's solving your problem don't forget to validate the answer

Comment: I did, but because I have less then 15 reputation it's recorded nbut not visible in public...

Comment: I upvoted your question that should be all right now ;-)
+ when someone provide a long answer and you want to add minor change (which is the case with your answer), just edit the existing answer instead of providing a new one

Comment: @JonasApelt, you actually upvoted the answer (which is very nice thanks) but you didn't accepted it (https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). It will improve the referencing of your question and reward me for the time I spend debugging your code ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it correctly. After some help by @Pierrick Rambaud I found out about the query itself. It still had an issue, that you couldn't query something from `df_bounds` if your bounding box was smaller than one object inside the DataFrame.

I finally added parameter `d`what equals `tile_width`. That allows you to actually receive correct results, even if your polygon bounds are smaller than the objects in your dataframe, you will always get at least one object returned.

````
import requests 
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

##########################
##      parameters      ##
##########################
tile_width = 1111950.5196666666
tile_height = 1111950.5196666666
d = tile_width

# Kölle
xmax, ymax, xmin, ymin = 517293, 5677545, 445982, 5652207
# Stocki
#xmax, ymax, xmin, ymin = -552726.6281122746, 7752304.739116074, -2367333.4095007353, 6772316.822647995

# todo : to name in parameters 
toto = -20015109.354
tutu = -10007554.677
##########################


# use the pathlib lib it's easyer to manipulate files and folder and I helps you get rid of compatibility problems
direc = Path().cwd()

#wd
url = 'https://modis-land.gsfc.nasa.gov/pdf/sn_bound_10deg.txt'
tiles_txt = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)

tile_bounds = direc.joinpath('tiles_bounds.txt') 
tile_bounds.write_bytes(tiles_txt.content)

# always open files with a with statement to avoid unclosed files
with tile_bounds.open() as f:
    text = f.read()
    text = text.splitlines()

    del text[0:7] 
    del text[-2:]
    
# the file is now useless unlink it 
tile_bounds.unlink()
    
df_bounds = pd.DataFrame(columns=['tile','horizontal', 'vertical','xmin_m','xmax_m', 'ymin_m', 'ymax_m'])
#df_bounds.tile = hv

hor, ver, xmin_m, xmax_m, ymin_m, ymax_m=[], [], [], [],[], []

# use the map function to add extra column to a dataframe, it's easier and faster 
df_bounds.tile = [f"h{text[i][5:7].replace(' ', '0')}v{text[i][1:3].replace(' ', '0')}" for i in range(len(text))]
df_bounds.horizontal = df_bounds.tile.map(lambda row: row[1:3]).astype(int)
df_bounds.vertical = df_bounds.tile.map(lambda row: row[4:6]).astype(int)
df_bounds.xmin_m = df_bounds.horizontal.map(lambda r: toto + r*tile_width)
df_bounds.ymin_m = df_bounds.vertical.map(lambda r: tutu + (17 - r)*tile_height)
df_bounds.xmax_m = df_bounds.xmin_m.map(lambda r: r + tile_width)
df_bounds.ymax_m = df_bounds.ymin_m.map(lambda r: r + tile_height)

#filter the names of the tiiles inside the box and add tile_widt/tile_height to receive valid results
tile_names = df_bounds[(df_bounds['xmin_m'] >= xmin-d) & 
                       (df_bounds['xmax_m'] <= xmax+d) & 
                       (df_bounds['ymin_m'] >= ymin-d) &
                       (df_bounds['ymax_m'] <= ymax+d)]

# improvement for the print 
tile_names = ','.join(tile_names.tile)

print('0',tile_names)# '1',tile_names_s)


```
````